# Where is the `end_lnum` field of the item in `setqflist`?

Tags: vimscript

As title. In `:h setqflist` there is no field `end_lnum` and `end_col`. While these options exist in `:h getqflist` . So my question is simple: If I cannot set it, how can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was added in [patch 8.2.3019](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/6864efa59636ccede2af24e3f5f92d78d210d77b).

Justification is given [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/8393) as follows:

> Modern tools may be able to specify a range when outputting the location of
> the source code.
>
> LSP reports the location of errors etc. in the range.
> The Rust compiler can report error locations in a range.
> ripgrep can get information on the end position of the match in JSON format.

Currently (as of Jan/31/22), there is no automatic setting of `end_lnum` and `end_col`, it is purely user-specified (i.e., for use in plugins).  There is a [proposal](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/9624) to add `%e` and `%k` specifiers to allow parsing from an errorfile (for such tools that emit these fields).

> If I cannot set it, how can I get it?

Actually, I think this is a documentation bug.  `setqflist` does support `end_lnum` and `end_col`, it just isn't documented as such.  Given the age of the patch, it is probably just an oversight or missed during documentation (runtime) updates by Bram.

Comment: "`setqflist` does support `end_lnum` and `end_col`, it just isn't documented as such": Could you provide the link to the source code? I didn't find it.

Comment: Is it stable to use these two fields now?

Comment: See https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/d82a47dd0493ee976aa3f15ecdc9aea7da6ad5bf/src/quickfix.c#L7165

and it sees to work for me: `call setqflist([{'end_lnum': 20, 'end_col': 10}])|echo getqflist()`

Comment: lol, I cannot believe that vi.stackexchange is better than reddit in terms of API professional level.

Comment: A little q: Do you know how to remove(is it even possible?) a single qflist, when there are many ones?

Comment: If you mean remove a single item, no I think the only action is replace, but if you mean replace a quickfix list, see the `nr` entry : `    :call setqflist([], 'a', {'nr' : 4, 'title' : 'SomeTitle'})
`